# Insert unique time span into table

Tags: javascript, c#, t-sql

I have table that contains 3 columns: start and end date of some event and event id.

I need to insert new row and somehow validate that time span between start and end date doesn't intersect with other time spans for this event.

For example I have 2 time spans for event: from 1.08.2016 to 9.08.2016 and from 10.08.2016 to 17.08.2016. So that I can't insert any new row that has start and end date between 1.08.2016 and 17.08.2016

How can I do this validation with JavaScript, C# or T-SQL?

Comment: Following along from your example, assuming your table has columns `id`, `start_date` and `end_date`, would it be worth checking if the to-be inserted start_date value < min(start_date column) and > max(end_date column)? Assuming all your events are contiguous. If they are not contiguous you'd need to loop through all of the event rows. Unless I'm missing something that should do?

Comment: Unfortunately, there could be gaps, like 1.08.16-9.08.16 and 13.08.16-15.08.16

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DataX TABLE (
     EventID            INT IDENTITY
    ,StartDate      DATE
    ,EndDate        DATE
    )

INSERT INTO @DataX VALUES
     ('2016-08-01','2016-08-09')
    ,('2016-08-10','2016-08-17')

DECLARE  @NewStart          DATE = '2016-08-05'
        ,@NewEnd            DATE = '2016-08-18'
        ,@NewStartValid     TINYINT
        ,@NewEndValid       TINYINT

;WITH Validate
    AS (
        SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN @NewStart BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VStart,
               SUM(CASE WHEN @NewEnd   BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VEnd
            FROM @DataX
        )

SELECT @NewStartValid = VStart, @NewEndValid = VEnd
    FROM Validate

SELECT @NewStartValid, @NewEndValid
```

Valid is 0, invalid is > 0. This example shows that the start date is  within one of the date ranges (result: 1) and the end date is not (result: 0).

Comment: I say invalid is > 0, but if we adopt the premise that your database is correct, it should never be able to be within more than one date range. My original idea was to do 1 - SUM to reverse the polarity--make Valid 1 and invalid 0. But then I started worrying about the sum > 1. But that should be impossible.

Comment: This is t-SQL, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for C#. To do this you'll need a form (window) with the following controls:

1. x1 "DataGridView" (The table to see the columns with data)
2. x1 "NumericUpDown" (To choose an event ID)
3. x2 "DateTimePicker" (The choose the starting and ending dates)
4. x1 "Button" (To add the event to the table)

Here you have the code:

```
// This is your table with data in three columns
DataTable events = new DataTable();

// When the program starts
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add the columns to the table
    events.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    events.Columns.Add("Start Date", typeof(DateTime));
    events.Columns.Add("End Date", typeof(DateTime));

    // Set data and formats
    dataGridView1.DataSource = events;
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // The way the date is shown
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // Ex. 27-07-2016
}

// Add The row containing information about the event
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Weather or not the row should be added
    bool addRow = true;

    // Skip this if no rows are added yet
    foreach (DataRow row in events.Rows)
    {
        // Row id and dates
        int eventId = (int)row[0];
        DateTime rowStartDate = (DateTime)row[1];
        DateTime rowEndDate = (DateTime)row[2];

        // If new start date lies inside the timespan of an existing event
        bool newStartDateBetween = rowStartDate.Date <= dateTimePicker1.Value.Date && rowEndDate.Date >= dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;

        // If new end date lies inside the timespan of an existing event
        bool newEndDateBetween = rowStartDate.Date <= dateTimePicker2.Value.Date && rowEndDate.Date >= dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;

        // If any of these statements are true, show the error and dont add the new row
        if (eventId == numericUpDown1.Value || newStartDateBetween || newEndDateBetween || dateTimePicker2.Value.Date < dateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
        {
            if (eventId == numericUpDown1.Value)
                MessageBox.Show("Event ID already taken!");

            if (newStartDateBetween)
                MessageBox.Show("The starting date is within the timespan of event ID: " + row[0] + "!");

            if (newEndDateBetween)
                MessageBox.Show("The ending date is within the timespan of event ID: " + row[0] + "!");

            if (dateTimePicker2.Value.Date < dateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
                MessageBox.Show("The ending date is before the starting date!");

            // Dont add the row
            addRow = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Add the row if no errors
    if (addRow)
        events.Rows.Add((int)numericUpDown1.Value, dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't help, because I'm working with bpm'online(if you know what it is)

Comment: Could you then just apply the logic?

Comment: I'll try all of your ideas tomorrow, hope one of them will help

Answer (score 0):

The following will return any conficts

```
Declare @Table table (EventID int,StartDate Date,EndDate Date)
Insert into @Table values 
(1,'2016-08-01','2016-08-09'),
(2,'2016-08-10','2016-08-17')

Declare @StartDate Date = '2016-08-05'
Declare @EndDate   Date = '2016-08-18'

Select * 
      ,ValidStart = IIF(@StartDate Between StartDate and EndDate,0,1)
      ,ValidEnd   = IIF(@EndDate   Between StartDate and EndDate,0,1)
 From @Table 
 Where @StartDate Between StartDate and EndDate
    or @EndDate   Between StartDate and EndDate
```

Returns

```
EventID StartDate   EndDate     ValidStart  ValidEnd
1       2016-08-01  2016-08-09  0           1
```